# Laravel Blade File Open as Blade Type in VSCode

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if it is possible to automatically set language mode to blade (currently HTML) whenever I open the blade.php file in VSCode? Because Laravel Blade Formater works fine with the blade language mode in VSCode.

I tried adding "files.associations": {"*.blade.php": "blade"} but its not working as what I expected.

Language mode: HTML,
Formatter: Not working
[image: Example code snippet]

Language mode: Blade,
Formatter: Working
[image: Example code snippet]

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on Super User.

Comment: @Sherwin Variancia you already said the solution, 
ctrl+shift+p -> user settings->file association-> add item "*.blade.php" give it value "php"